# How to change of variables in the multiple integral to $UV$ plane?

Tags: calculus, integration

everyone; I have a question to ask you about this.
I have to solve this $$\int\limits_0^1\int_\limits0^{(1-x)}(y-2x)^2\sqrt{(x+y)}\ \mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$ with using change of variables to UV plane. we have $u=x+y$ and $v=y-2x$.

I find the equation from $xy$ plane. I have $u=1$ from $y=1-x$ and $u=0=v$ from $x=0=y$.

The question is, how to find the remaining equation? I try to use $u-v=x+y-(y-2x)$ and then I have $u=v$ but is it true?

Please, someone, give me a hint for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by drawing a picture:
[image]
Your original domain is the triangle formed by $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$. Constant $u=x+y$ lines are like the red one. The minimum value of $u$ is $0$ (through the origin) and the maximum is $1$ (when it's the same as the blue). $v=y-2x$lines are like the orange line. So we must restrict the range of $v$ values in such a way to keep from the red line only the segment inside the triangle, in this case the intersection with the axes. So for a given $u$, the intersections in terms of $x$ and $y$ are $(u,0)$ and $(0,u)$. We transform these into $v$: $0-2u=-2u$ and $u-2\cdot 0=u$. So you get $$\int_0^1du\int_{-2u}^udv...$$ Don't forget the Jacobian

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The original bounds are $0 \leq x + y \leq 1, x, y \geq 0$

As $u = x + y$, first find the bounds of $u$ which is straightforward.

Now, $v = y - 2x = (x + y) - 3x$ and we know $0 \leq x \leq x + y$ for $x, y \geq 0$. Do you see why that leads to the bounds of $v$ as $~-2 u \leq v \leq u~$?

Comment: Could I ask a question? Is the UV plane may not necessary rectangle?